# Messagebox issue with If

Tags: c#, telerik, windows-phone

I'm having weird behavior with my messagebox

here is the code:

```
private async void rate_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e) {
    string id = (string)((Image)sender).Tag;
    ignoreSelectionChanged = true;

    MobileServiceCollection<rating, rating> items;
    IMobileServiceTable<rating> itemTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<rating>();
    items = await itemTable
        .Where(Table => Table.userid == userId)
        .ToCollectionAsync();

    if (id != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {
            if (items[i].itemid == id) {
                MessageBox.Show("You already giving your rating.");
                i = items.Count;
                return;
            }
            else {
                RadMessageBox.Show(
                    new string[] { "very accurate", "not accurate" },
                    "Acurate?",
                    "Is this information accurate?", closedHandler: (args) => {
                        int buttonIndex = args.ButtonIndex;

                        if (buttonIndex == 0) {
                            clearListBox();
                            ratingPlus(id);
                            saveRating(id);
                            mvm.LoadDetailData();
                        }

                        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
                            clearListBox();
                            ratingMinus(id);
                            saveRating(id);
                            mvm.LoadDetailData();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        }                  
    }
}
```

What my code above dord is I trigger `rate_Tap()` from my listbox that already contains image, and each time I tap it , it's supposed to check with my windows azure server and check if there is an `itemid` that equals `id`. Then I will show messagebox saying I already rated it and if there isn't any `itemid` that equals `id` then it will execute radmessagebox.

But it's not working that way: when it checks there is an `itemid` that's equal to `id`, it shows the messagebox and after that it show the radmessagebox.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Could you make the example the **simplest that _still shows the issue_?**

Answer (score 1):

Your "else" block contains the code that you want to execute after you've checked *all* items - not on *each* item.

I think you want:

```
if (items.Any(item => item.itemid == id))
{
    MessageBox.Show("You already giving your rating.");
    return;
}
RadMessageBox.Show(...);
// etc
```

Ideally, don't fetch *all* the previous ratings - change your query so that it includes the ID of the item you're trying to rate. After all, you *only* want to know whether or not you've already rated it - the rest of the information is pointless, so why fetch it all?